# page search result. hide sidebar

Tags: catalogsearch

I need to hide the sidebar in the page search result.

In file local.xml and catalogsearch.xml there is

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>

    </catalogsearch_result_index>
```

i have changed this in

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>

    </catalogsearch_result_index>
```

but the sidebar remain also "The search returned no results"
I have tried also with

```
<remove name="left"/>
```

but "The search returned no results".

Another solution?
Thanks
Ale